# AutoLS for fish shell

Tags: fish

I have an `auto-ls` script in my `conf.d` directory

```
function __autols_hook --description "Auto ls" --on-event fish_prompt
  if test "$__autols_last" != (pwd)
    if test "$HOME" = (pwd)
    else
      clear; ls;
      # Show git information, and if it's not a git repo, throw error
      # into /dev/null. Simples
      git status 2>/dev/null
    end
  end
  set  -g __autols_last (pwd)
end
```

This works very well. However, I'd also like this to trigger when I hit enter, in the same pwd, but with no command.

I can't find a way to check if the enter key was pressed but no command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the binding for the [enter] key:

```
bind \cm 'set -l cmd (commandline); test -z "$cmd"; and set -g _empty_command yes; or set -g _empty_command no; commandline -f execute'
```

Now you can test `$_empty_command` in your fish_prompt event function. Note that [ctrl-j] also invokes the execute command so you should probably also `bind \cj` to the same code. But that's optional unless you have an unusual terminal config.

Comment: Thank you, Kurtis! Works like a charm

Comment: You mean like `if test "$__autols_last" != (pwd); or [ $_empty_command = yes ]`, right?